# Can Visual Studio 2017 remove space around = like Vs2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2017, autoformatting

I setup Visual Studio to remove all spaces in C# code, also around declarations/assignments.

I want

```
int x = 5;
```

to be automatically formatted like

```
int x=5;
```

In Visual Studio 2010 this works fine, the "Ignore spaces in declaration statements" option is off.
In Visual Studio 2017 many spaces are removed per my settings, e.g. around "+" or ",", but not assignments.
I can enable "Ignore spaces in declaration statements", then at least it will not insert the spacing upon triggering autoformat, but I would like it to automatically remove them.
Is this a regression to Vs2010?

I have unchecked all checkboxes for inserting spaces and chosen "Remove spacing before and after binary operators"

The same issue happens with Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Even if I knew how to do this, I wouldn't tell you, that's awful! My opinion of course, but ugh! :)

Comment: Text Editor - C# - Code Style - Formatting - Spacing - Set spacing for operators - Remove spaces before and after binary operators?

Comment: @GSerg It doesn't work for expression assignments.

Comment: Here's an example why I don't like this: `Func<int,int> thing=x =>5;`. To me, that is quite unreadable.

Comment: It should look like Func<int,int> thing=x=>5; according to my preferred style. I'm sorry, I'm used to it and I just want vs2017 to do the same as vs2010.

Answer (score 2):

You should look in Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> C# --> Formatting --> Spacing and then change the option under "Set Spacing for Operators".

Comment: I have selected "Remove spacing before and after binary operators" just like in vs2010

Comment: Try turning off auto formatting then. Go to Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> C# --> Formatting -->General and uncheck all the boxes. Then, go back to Spacing tab and check "ignore spaces" wherever it lets you do so.

Comment: There is only one "ignore spacing". I would like to keep autoformatting, I want my code to be formatted according to my preferred style.